# Cleric/wizard or Cleric/fighter? Rolled decent stats so IDK

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric

So I have a choice between rolled stats.

18,16,15,12,11,10 -- 14,13,13,13,13,13

I am definitely interested in doing a cleric and it seems best to do a hill dwarf.

At first, I was thinking of doing a cleric/wizard build, using blur, and mage armor to act as a secondary tank and healer. I am not sure if the campaign will last to level 20. Basically wearing a shield, and open hand.

However, with stats, I am thinking more of cleric/fighter build just wanted to see what your thoughts were.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Please take the [tour] to learn more about how we do things around here. Unfortunately we don’t do idea-generation questions. We focus on question with objectively correct answers. Once you get enough reputation you can join us in the chat!

Comment: Hi Albert, welcome to RPG:SE - hopefully you find it a really useful resource. You've asked a great question but it's not one that works well on the stack exchange question and answer format, as Christopher said. With that in mind,  [here are some forums which might be more help with this sort of question.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) Don't take this personally, this community really is very friendly and would love to help with any questions that might have more objective answers.